# Windows Command To Get User Accounts Which Have Been Inactive For 90 Or More Days

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I am trying to craft a windows command that outputs a list of user accounts that have been inactive for 90 or more days.

Using the PowerShell command below, I can see that there is a parameter for the users called "Last Logon", can this be used to achieve this test? And if yes, can you please help me craft this command?

```
get-localuser | Select *
```

Comment: You're using `Get-LocalUser`, so are you not on a domain?

Comment: @Theo Yes, only looking for local users and not domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only care about local users, there is a `LastLogon` property on the returned type that you will care about:

```
# a known user
$user = Get-LocalUser -Name Administrator
# print the datetime of last logon; this can be null
$user.LastLogon

# get our current date and subtract 90 days
$stamp = [datetime]::Now.AddDays(-90)

if ($user.LastLogon -lt $stamp) {
    "user $user hasn't logged on in over 90 days"
}
```

You will want to take care you don't try to remove built-in user objects.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
get-localuser | Where-Object { (New-Timespan -Start $_.LastLogon -End (Get-Date)).Days -ge 90 }
```